# Rails Link_to text but not display Class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have use Rails link_to and CSS class without any problem, but I think I am using right but it not show at all

as I am trying to create CSS as Accept ( green background color) and Decline ( red background color)

as simple based text

```
<p class="text-center"><%= reservation.status %></p>
   <div class="form-inline">
      <% if reservation.Waiting? %>
      <%= link_to approve_reservation_path(reservation), class:"btn-declined", method: :post do %>  <% end %>
      <%= link_to decline_reservation_path(reservation), class:"btn-approved", method: :post do %>  <% end %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

as have used different way but no CSS display only text

[image]

the console log shows no CSS for accepting and decline on it

[image]

CSS code

[image]

what is an alternative way to get display CSS on it

Comment: `<%= link_to "Approve", approve_reservation_path(reservation), class:"btn-declined", method: :post %>` add this without `do`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<p class="text-center"><%= reservation.status %></p>
 <div class="form-inline">
  <% if reservation.Waiting? %>
  <%= link_to "Approve", approve_reservation_path(reservation), class:"btn-declined", method: :post %>
  <%= link_to "Decline", decline_reservation_path(reservation), class:"btn-approved", method: :post %>
  <% end %>
```

the links will only show if `<% if reservation.Waiting? %>` becomes true.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I need change code on reservation.status not reservation.waiting ?, my mistake. seems i overlook it

Comment: Got fix it but u are right but  i was a wrong div section as i am using on                             <% if reservation.status == "Approved" %>
                                    <p class="text-center btn-approved">Approved</p>
                                <% else reservation.status == "Declined" %>
                                    <p class="text-center btn-declined">Declined</p>
                                <% end %>

Comment: happy that it got fixed.!!